# Detecting text encapsulation in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text, encapsulation, detect

In my program I need to make various word replacements but I don't want to replace the word if it's encapsulated. Here's an example:

> This is an example. Here is the {definition of example}: A small part
>   or quantity intended to show what the whole is like. Examples are great.

I would like it to turn that into this:

> This is an replacement words. Here is the {definition of example}: A small part
>   or quantity intended to show what the whole is like. replacement words are great.

Sorry, I don't have any code to show progress yet aside from my current code to make replacements and that won't help with this problem.

Thanks!
Phil

Comment: I suggest reading up on regular expressions

Comment: I really don't know much at all about regex, would it be possible to create a regex string that matches all text outside of an {} encapsulation but ignores the string if it's contained in {}?

Comment: Yes. That is precisely why I recommended you look at them!

Comment: OK, thanks! Would +up you but I can't in comments.

Comment: Yeah you can :) Just hover over the comment and there is a little ^ button :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is using Regular Expressions.

A great tool for experimenting with and learning Regular Expressions is [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) (it provides detailed explanations of entered Regex's).

- [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx)
- [Using Regular Expressions with The Microsoft .NET Framework](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html)
- [Regular expressions - An introduction](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html)
- [Regex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: And look at a regex editor to test and play around with.  I like this one, but there are others.  http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/